# Django gunicorn nginx 111 connection refused while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

A fresh Django application is running on the Debian server, configured via gunicorn and nginx. After setup i tried to connect to it, but i can reach it only by server ip and [www.mydomain.ru](http://www.mydomain.ru), but not by mydomain.ru. The only error i found is in nginx log:

```
2023/08/10 16:08:48 [error] 19252#19252: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.xx.xxx.xxx, server: mydomain.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80"
```

or sometimes host: "mydomain.ru"

my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.ru;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/alex/myproject;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/alex/myproject;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.ru;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/alex/myproject;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/alex/myproject;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

my gunicorn.conf

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
workers = 2
user = 'alex'
timeout = 120
```

mydomain.ru is in django settings ALLOWED_HOSTS and CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS, but anyway, when i `python3 manage.py runserver` django shows some activity only accessing it by server ip and www.

when i stop project with supervisor there are no other servers in `netstat -tpln`

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      324/zabbix_agentd   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20083/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      358/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17127/postgres      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      358/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      17127/postgres
```

and it is there when i start project =)

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20564/python3.9
```

I tried every options i found here, googled or got from chatgpt, but nothing helps me. Please, help me in this question, it will make me very happy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest post this question on serfault stackexchange there you will get better answer as that site is meant for server issues https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Also i think it might be firewall issue just check inbound and outbound connection

Comment: @Ahtisham i tried to check firewall settings but nothing wrong there, default files. But i noticed that i can reach site with www subdomain... maybe it will clarify smth. Thanks for serverfault.com, did not know about it